# How to cancel circle select mode by 'X' key instead of ESC key?

Tags: selection-tools, shortcut

I noticed I use left sided keys frequently and did some customized but one remains.
1. Remove Delete function from X key because pressed accidentally many times.
2. And I want to assign 'Canceling Circle Select mode' by press X key instead of distanced ESC key.

I done step.1 but couldn't find how to do step.2, remap X key as cancel circle select mode. Initially I remapped by AutoHotKey but soon I noticed I couldn't type X character(when renaming/creating object &file)...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know you can exit circle select using the (even less distanced) right mouse button?

Comment: oh i didn't know that. what a convenient way... Huge Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can't change the <kbd>Escape</kbd> keybinding, which is also used by many other operators.

But there are other (quicker) methods to exit circle selection.

From the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/selecting/tools.html#circle-select):

> To cancel the selection use <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> or key <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd>.

- **Press the <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>.**
- If you're right-handed, awkwardly swivel your right thumb onto <kbd>Numpad Enter</kbd>.
- If you have a programmable mouse, assign any of its buttons to <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Escape</kbd>, this would be a useful keybind anyway which is not wasted.